# Combination of numeric and price format - TextBox of WPF

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, textbox

I have using this code for getting price from user

```
<TextBox Name="txtPrice" PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationTextBox" />
```

And I am forcing the user to enter only numbers

```
private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    Regex regex1 = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
    e.Handled = regex1.IsMatch(e.Text);
}
```

How could I provide format of price too, like :

```
123,700
```

Comment: Just set `StringFormat` for `TextBox.Text` if you bind `Text` on some viewmodel value

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria please write a sample that works with both stringformat 000,000,000 and numeric

Comment: @AbdullahDibas I test all of them, isn't work

Comment: `var strFormat = "#,#"; var str = 123456789.ToString(strFormtat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 0):

Testing if a string is correctly formatted as a number with optional thousand-separator:

```
^\d+(,\d{3})*$
```

[Live demo.](https://regex101.com/r/91UR3L/2)

Comment: I try to provide it like Regex regex1 = new Regex("^\d+(,\d{3})*$");  but Visual said, "Bad Compile constant value"

Comment: @alihaghdoust9 just try to add `@`: `Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"^\d+(,\d{3})*$");`

Comment: hmm, it hasn't bug now, but on this case I can write any character from A to Z

Comment: In Java an escape character needs an extra escape. So `\\d` instead of `\d`. This might be the same for c#.

Comment: @linden2015 Thanks for your help, \\ isn't solve